# What is going wrong that I'm seeing this script error in the auto-editor program I'm running?

Tags: python, audio, video, editor, editing

I'm currently using this auto-editor for video production:

https://github.com/WyattBlue/auto-editor

Normally it works beautifully!
However, seemingly at random, sometimes I will get this error block:

```
stderr: Input #0, rawvideo, from 'pipe:':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: 331776 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (I420 / 0x30323449), yuv420p, 1280x720, 331776 kb/s, 30 tbr, 30 tbn
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> h264 (libopenh264))
[libopenh264 @ 000002037b2da400] Slice count will be set automatically
[libopenh264 @ 000002037b2da400] [OpenH264] this = 0x000002037B0B1290, Warning:layerId(0) doesn't support profile(578), change to UNSPECIFIC profile
[libopenh264 @ 000002037b2da400] [OpenH264] this = 0x000002037B0B1290, Warning:bEnableFrameSkip = 0,bitrate can't be controlled for RC_QUALITY_MODE,RC_BITRATE_MODE and RC_TIMESTAMP_MODE without enabling skip frame.
[libopenh264 @ 000002037b2da400] [OpenH264] this = 0x000002037B0B1290, Warning:Change QP Range from(0,51) to (12,42)
Output #0, mp4, to 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpc34z4dni\spedup0.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf59.17.101
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 10000 kb/s, 30 fps, 15360 tbn
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc59.20.100 libopenh264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 10000000/0/10000000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
[mp4 @ 000002037b2d6d40] Starting second pass: moving the moov atom to the beginning of the file
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lsize=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x
video:0kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown

Error! FFmpeg Error!
```

I've followed every related troubleshooting guide on the github page, but none of the solutions seem to work.

I've uninstalled and reinstalled python, the auto-editor, and ffmpeg multiple times. I've moved the downloads for each around to be nested, on the same drive, and on different drives. I made sure that everything was properly in the path in my global variables. Normally it's a pretty quick script so I kept expecting that something would work but now I am stuck.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming messages and not usage issues.   Your question sounds more like a support question rather than a programming one.  If it is a support question, try asking the author.

Comment: I haven't heard back from the creator. I was hoping someone would be familiar with the functionality and could potentially suggest code edits to make it work(or a simpler resolution, if it exists)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.